# Knockout Dynamic Comment style binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, data-binding, knockout.js

Is there a way that i can use comment style binding with dynamically created elements. The code snipped is the following:

```
      `<div id="lc-waiting-list" class="waiting-list form-group">
            <!-- ko if: UsersCallingMe().length > 0 -->
            <!-- ko foreach: UsersCallingMe-->
            <div class="single-user">
                <div class="user-name" data-bind="text: Username, attr: { 'data-cid': ConnectionId }"></div>
                <div class="user-accept"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>`
```

this snipped is added dynamically, but the binding are not working.
I've tried to do:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('#lc-waiting-list'));
```

but unfortunately an exception was raised, that the element could not be binded twice.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `document.getElementById('#lc-waiting-list')` - the `#` is not needed - the ID is just `lc-waiting-list`. Other than that, what do you neam by "dynamically added elements"? Are they added outside KO or is this generated by KO but somehow it isn't bound to the appropriate model? Can you make a small example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Problem was solved. I was not using the right array and the typo that you've mentioned has made it work. Tnx.

Comment: the changes were from:

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('#lc-waiting-list'));

to:

ko.applyBindings(viewModel.UsersCallingMe, document.getElementById('lc-waiting-list'));